# looking for example to instrument Javascript/Angular client with AWS XRay

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

We are trying to instrument angular/Javascript browser-side/client-side with Aws XRay, can someone provide me an example or point to a reference.

Answer (score 0):

The X-Ray SDK for Node.js is intended for server-side use with web frameworks or serverless architecture. We cannot provide any official support or guarantees for your use case, but if you'd like you can try to [develop some custom instrumentation](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/tree/master/packages/core#developing-custom-solutions-using-automatic-mode). You can also refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs.html) for more info.